# Karma tests doesn't execute while parsing javascript imports in a typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-typescript

I have been building a typescript based app which uses a few reusable web components written in javascript.

Something like this:

**test.ts**

```
import { jsModule } from 'components/module.js';
...
```

So, now while writing unit tests, **karma-typescript** doesn't understand the javascript imports and throw me this error without executing the tests.

```
ERROR [transformer.karma-typescript]: components/module.js: Unexpected token (44:35)
Transform function:
...
```

What could be an elegant way to write tests for a typescript file having javascript imports, does anyone know what should karma config hold to execute tests in a scenario like this?

Comment: will it be possible for you to include what code is in `components/module.js`?

Comment: Also, are you compiling(running a `tsc`) before starting `karma`?

Comment: @NalinRanjan It's an example snippet on how I am importing a js module in typescript file. No, I am not running `tsc` I am writing tests for the `src`, not for the transpiled files.

Comment: `import { jsModule } from 'components/module.js';` isn't a relative import. Are these files in `components` part of your source or are they packages?

Comment: And a snippet from `module.js` will indeed help...

Comment: @NalinRanjan These are being imported from `node_modules`

Comment: Two things can really help... 1) your `tsconfig.json` 2) Which package is that which you are importing ? Any url or npm link will do...

Comment: Also, if any `karma.conf.js`...